# Beginner: python, issue with output

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to program a simulation of selling theater tickets in python.  The program will calculate the total income after it has filled in the number of adults, children and seniors, but inspecting the income and the percentage-of seats always shows 0.
I have issues with percentage_sold and sum_income.
Can anyone help me?

```
   ## -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

import os
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Theater:
        def __init__(self, name, seats, price_adult, price_child, price_senior):
                self.name = name
                self.seats = seats
                self.price_adult = price_adult
                self.price_child = price_child
                self.price_senior = price_senior
                self.sold_adult = IntVar(root)
                self.sold_child = IntVar(root)
                self.sold_senior = IntVar(root)
                self.percentage_sold = IntVar(root)
                self.sum_income = IntVar(root)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.name

root = Tk()
root.title("Teater ekonomi")

def create_list(FILENAME):      
        f = open(FILENAME, "r") 
        theater_list = []
        parts = []
        for line in f:
                parts = line.strip().split('/')
                theater_list.append(Theater(parts[0], int(parts[1]), 
                int(parts[2]), int(parts[3]), int(parts[4])))
        f.close()
        return theater_list

def calculate_profits(theater_list):
        for thing in theater_list:

                thing.percentage_sold = int(((thing.sold_adult 
                + thing.sold_child + thing.sold_senior) / (float)thing.seats) * 100)

                thing.sum_income = ((thing.sold_adult * thing.price_adult) 
                + (thing.sold_child * thing.price_child) + (thing.sold_senior * thing.price_senior))

FILENAME = "teatrar.txt"
error_message = ""
if os.path.isfile(FILENAME):
        try:
                theater_list = create_list(FILENAME)
        except ValueError:
                error_message = "Filen 'teatrar.txt' är korrupt.\nProgrammet kan inte fortsätta."
else:
        error_message = "Filen 'teatrar.txt' existerar inte eller är inte i programmappen.\nProgrammet kan inte fortsätta."


mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

if error_message != "":
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text=error_message, justify="center").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
else:
        theater_names_col = []
        theater_ticket_one = []
        theater_ticket_two = []
        theater_ticket_three = []
        theater_perc_row = []
        theater_profits_row = []

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Teatrar").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(W))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Vuxenbiljetter").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Barnbiljetter").grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=(W))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Pensionärbiljetter").grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=(W))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Procent fullsatt").grid(column=8, row=1, sticky=(W))
        ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Inkomst för kvällen").grid(column=10, row=1, sticky=(W))

        for x, y in enumerate(theater_list):
                ttk.Label(mainframe, text="st").grid(column=3, row=x+2, sticky=(W))
                ttk.Label(mainframe, text="st").grid(column=5, row=x+2, sticky=(W))
                ttk.Label(mainframe, text="st").grid(column=7, row=x+2, sticky=(W))
                ttk.Label(mainframe, text="%").grid(column=9, row=x+2, sticky=(W))
                ttk.Label(mainframe, text="kr").grid(column=11, row=x+2, sticky=(W))

                theater_names_col.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, text=y.name).grid(column=1, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))
                theater_ticket_one.append(ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=y.sold_adult, justify="right").grid(column=2, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))
                theater_ticket_two.append(ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=y.sold_child, justify="right").grid(column=4, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))
                theater_ticket_two.append(ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable=y.sold_senior, justify="right").grid(column=6, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))
                theater_perc_row.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=y.percentage_sold, justify="right").grid(column=8, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))
                theater_profits_row.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=y.sum_income, justify="right").grid(column=10, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E)))



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: where do you use calculate_profits() .

Comment: 'theater_perc_row.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=y.percentage_sold, justify="right").grid(column=8, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E))) theater_profits_row.append(ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=y.sum_income, justify="right").grid(column=10, row=x+2, sticky=(W,E))) '

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to make sure you are doing float division and not integer division.  The easiest way is to cast one of the operands to float:

```
# instead of
seats_filled = seats_sold / total_seats
# have
seats_filled = seats_sold / float(total_seats)
```

Besides the issue with `float`, when using `IntVar`, `StringVar`, `BooleanVar`, and `DoubleVar` you must use the `.set(xxx)` to change the value and `.get()` to retrieve the current value.

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: @user3657176: Hopefully that helps.